# Read Write to Memory space

Tags: c, fpga, zynq, petalinux

I am trying to write a Signed Double number to memory and read back the same, reading back is redundant as it is just to verify if the correct data is in the memory before I trigger the PL (programmable logic) FPGA Fabric to access this data and perform a task.

I read a file into a double (part of a union) and then write to memory through the unsigned long (part of a union). But the data before writing into memory and after I read out is wrong, it is just the last byte. (see the code and comments for details)

```
union floatpun {
    double dw;
    unsigned long lw;
};

void *lookup_slave_by_phy_addr(const int fd, const off_t target, const size_t mapsize)
{
  void *map_base, *virt_addr;

  /* Map one page */
  map_base = mmap(0, mapsize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, target & ~(mapsize-1));
  if (map_base == (void *) -1) { FATAL; }
  printf("Memory mapped at address %p.\n", map_base);
  fflush(stdout);

  virt_addr = map_base + (target & (mapsize-1));
  return virt_addr;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
  union floatpun conv;

  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("/media/card/numbers.txt", "r");
  fscanf(fp,"%lf",&conv.dw);  // 0.009101592004299160 Reads this number from the file, which is correct as expected.
  printf("The value Read from the File is %lx \n",conv.lw); // Prints 3f 82 a3 da ff ff ff fe, which is also correct.
  fclose(fp);

  int fd;
  if ((fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC)) == -1) { FATAL; }
  printf("/dev/mem opened.\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  void *weights;
  // Map systemMemory master phy address range 0000 0008 7000 0000 -> 0000 0008 7FFF FFFF
  weights       = lookup_slave_by_phy_addr(fd,strtoul("0x0000000870000000",0,0),MAP_SIZE_256M);
    *((unsigned char *) (weights+0x00))  = conv.lw;   // Writing into the mempory
    SysMem= *((unsigned char *) (weights+0x00));    // Reading it out from the memory
    printf("Read %lx\n", SysMem);                   // When this is printed I get only FE, the last byte of the data read from the file, I have read the following 0x01, 02 03 also, which are all junk data like 0x69 0x95 0x9A

  close(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

What mistake am I doing in writing to memory or reading from the memory, I want this complete 64 bit written to the memory. Or should I manually write each byte to a byte of memory, arent the memory word (32 Bit) addressable? or if not can I make it a word addressable?

Also, this is being done on Zynq with Petalinux

Please help :)

Comment: silly question but is `sizeof(double) == sizeof(unsigned long)` on your system?

Comment: yes they both are 8 bytes 
Size of Double 8, Size of UL 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
    *((unsigned char *) (weights+0x00))  = conv.lw;   // Writing into the mempory
    SysMem= *((unsigned char *) (weights+0x00));    // Reading it out from the memory
```

You're casting your `(void *) weights` as a `(unsigned char *)`, then storing the value of `conv.lw` at that pointer location.
But by doing that type-cast, you've explicitly told your compiler that you only want to write a single `unsigned char`, so it quite happily does that with the least-significant byte of `conv.lw`.
Similarly, when you read it back, you again cast `weights` as an `(unsigned char *)` and so you're only reading a singe byte form that location.

If you  instead did something like:

```
    *((unsigned long *) (weights+0x00))  = conv.lw;   // Writing into the mempory
    SysMem= *((unsigned long *) (weights+0x00));    // Reading it out from the memory
```

you'd be writing and reading all the bytes of `conv.lw`.

There are also a few reasons which make what you're trying to do non-portable, including: `unsigned long` is only typically only 4 bytes on a 32-bit architecture, and dereferencing pointers cast from other types is (at least sometimes) undefined behavior.

Comment: If they are going to write all the bytes as one object, they might as well just write a `double`. If that cannot work due to alignment or other issues, they should just `memcpy` between the `double` and the memory. Either way, they do not need the union or `unsigned long *`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - true. I was just trying to keep within the spirit of the original code... The intent could certainly be expressed better.

Comment: Thank you so much brhans !!, so silly of me to miss the type I am writing it to.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment `*((unsigned char *) (weights+0x00))  = conv.lw;` writes only a single `unsigned char`, and `SysMem= *((unsigned char *) (weights+0x00));` reads only a single `unsigned char`.

To write and read a `double`, use either:

```
* (double *) weights = conv.dw;
double x = * (double *) weights;
printf("%a\n", x); // Or use %g or %f.
```

or:

```
memcpy(weights, conv.dw, sizeof conv.dw);
double x;
memcpy(x, weights, sizeof x);
printf("%a\n", x); // Or use %g or %f.
```

The first method requires that `weights` be suitably aligned for your platform (it looks like it would be in your example code). There should not be aliasing issues directly from this code since `conv.dw` is accessed as its proper type (`double`), and `weights` is effectively a dynamically allocated object (providing your code for getting its value is correct, and presumably your compiler supports this), so a `double` is effectively created at `weights` by writing a `double` to there.

The second method should work regardless of alignment, provided the address in `weights` is properly accessible in your process.

In either case, there is no need for the union. The `double` can be used directly, without aliasing it with an `unsigned long`.

Comment: Eric Postpischil , Thank you so much for fixing my issue !!